# Reading files with use of Delimiter in Java

Tags: java, io, readfile

I am trying to read text file with 3 lines:

10

PA/123#PV/573#Au/927#DT/948#HY/719#ZR/741#bT/467#LR/499#Xk/853#kD/976#

15.23#25.0#17.82#95.99#23.65#156.99#72.85#62.99#112.0#55.99#

So far in my main method I have:

```
 `String fileName = "productData.txt";

    String line = null;

    try {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }`
```

But Im not sure how I would go on with using the String DELIMITER = "#";

In the text file Line 1: is applied to number of types of product, Line 2: are product codes separated by #, and in Line 3: Price per unit of the corresponding products separated by #.

So Im looking for kind of format PA/123 Costs 15.23. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can you `line.split('#');` to get an array of Strings. This array contains your 10 elements. 
Then you have two arrays of size 10. So `firstArray[0]` contains the name of the first product and `secondArray[0]` contains the price of it.